# Find coordinates of an array

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, vector, indexing

I have a three-dimensional array x created as:

```
vector1 <- c(5, 9, 2)
vector2 <- c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
  
x <- array(c(vector1, vector2), dim = c(3, 3, 2))
print(x)

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5   10   13
[2,]    9   11   14
[3,]    2   12   15

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5   10   13
[2,]    9   11   14
[3,]    2   12   15
```

I need to find the coordinates, i.e. the three dimensions positions of the minimum element of the array. This is what I did:

```
which.min(x)
[1] 16

x[16]
[1] 2
```

Now I know which is the minimum number but how do I find the coordinates of this number (i.e. [3,1,2])?
I already tried

```
which(x == 2, arr.ind = TRUE)
```

but the output is this:

```
dim1 dim2 dim3
```

how can I get what I'm looking for?

Comment: Please check the values of the array. i..e if the value is `2.000001`, the `==` will return FALSE.  It is possible that the value may not be exactly equal to 2. Try with `which(x == min(x), arr.ind = TRUE)`

Comment: Please post a reproducible example, i.e. one we can cut and paste to see what you saw.

Comment: I tried that but it's still outputting: dim1 dim2 dim3

Comment: Thanks for editing the code in.  When I run `which(x == min(x), arr.ind = TRUE)`, I get the two solutions printed as a two row matrix:  `[1,]    3    1    1` and `[2,]    3    1    2`.

Comment: hi you're defintely right. My array is not the same as this one. I just used this one because it was easier to understand but there must be something wrong with mine. THanks!

Comment: It's important to post reproducible examples so as not to waste everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misinterpreting the output. The "dim1 dim2 dim3" are not the result. They are just the column names of the result which is actually 2 x 3 numeric matrix.

```
which(x == 2, arr.ind = TRUE)
#     dim1 dim2 dim3
#[1,]    3    1    1
#[2,]    3    1    2
```

It's telling you that there are two 2's in that array since there are two rows with index values as results. If you wanted the result of c(3,1,2) it would be the second row:

```
 arr <- which(x == 2, arr.ind = TRUE)
unname(arr[2, ])    # to remove the names that were confusing you.
#[1] 3 1 2
```

Since your comments suggested that you might have a floating point issue, I will create an example by modifying your so that you cna see that R only displays a limited precion for elements of metrices and arrays which may hide very small discrepancies from immediate viewing.

```
 x[3] <- 2.000000001   # small increment
> x
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5   10   13
[2,]    9   11   14
[3,]    2   12   15

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    5   10   13
[2,]    9   11   14
[3,]    2   12   15

> which.min(x)
[1] 12                  twelfth item now the min
> which(x == min(x), arr.ind=TRUE)
     dim1 dim2 dim3
[1,]    3    1    2     # the array index for the 12th item
```